# Different session timeouts for different users in same web app

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a requirement within the same web application to set 2 session timeouts.

60 minutes for regular users and 3 hours for admin users.

I am told this is not possible and I will need to host a separate web app for the admins.

Is there any workaround?

UPDATE:
Thanks to Bozho and Kurt's replies - I have a followup question.

Does session.setMaxInactiveInterval() override the value of session timeout set via web.xml ?

Comment: As per your update: no, it doesn't and you have to (re)set it on **every** request. A `Filter` is the best place for this.

Comment: The Java Servlet specification seems to indicate that set setMaxInactiveInterval does indeed override the session-timeout value in web.xml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [`session.setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29)

Comment: I think your replys was marginally quicker than Kurt

Answer (score 4):

When I look at the `HttpSession` interface, I see the following method.

`setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)`: Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet container will invalidate this session.